# List sqlite3 extensions that are loaded?

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to have SQLite3 list the extensions that it has loaded? I'd like to know if the FTS3, FTS4 or FTS5 extension are loaded, without just trying functions and see if they work.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_module_list for extensions that provide virtual tables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use:

sqlite> PRAGMA compile_options;