# How can I find with what extensions has my copy of sqlite been built?

Tags: json, sqlite, error-handling, syntax-error

I have a script involving sqlite3 which runs fine on one system but malfunctions on a different system, complaining about the SQL syntax. The syntax relies on the sqlite JSON extension, so I suspect the malfunctioning sqlite has just not been compiled with support for this extension. (It comes from the linux distribution; if I really have to I'll hunt down the package source.) How can I confirm or deny this hunch? `sqlite3 -version` doesn't provide this information, unfortunately.

Bonus question: It seems sqlite exits with status 0 even after it complains after these errors! This has caused me to lose a bunch of data (because the script merrily proceeded to its cleanup stage). Isn't this a bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List sqlite3 extensions that are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748608/list-sqlite3-extensions-that-are-loaded)

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks! Feel free to mark my question as duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The JSON functions and operators are built into SQLite by default, as
> of SQLite version 3.38.0 (2022-02-22).

> They can be omitted by adding
> the -DSQLITE_OMIT_JSON compile-time option. Prior to version 3.38.0,
> the JSON functions were an extension that would only be included in
> builds if the -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 compile-time option was included.
> In other words, the JSON functions went from being opt-in with SQLite
> version 3.37.2 and earlier to opt-out with SQLite version 3.38.0 and
> later.